# Задача "Несправедливые башни"

Tags: python-3.x

Помогите, пожалуйста, никак не могу решить данную задачу. Нужно сделать через рекурсию на python, но не понимаю как. Может у кого есть идея?

Головоломка “Ханойские башни” состоит из трёх стержней, пронумерованных числами 1, 2, 3. На стержень 1 надета пирамидка из n дисков различного диаметра в порядке возрастания диаметра дисков, если рассматривать их сверху вниз. Диски можно перекладывать с одного стержня на другой по одному, при этом диск нельзя класть на диск меньшего диаметра. Необходимо переложить всю пирамидку со стержня 1 на стержень 3, используя стержень 2 как вспомогательный. Но после в Ханое несправедливо запретили класть самый маленький диск (номер 1) на средний колышек (номер 2). Решите головоломку с учётом этих ограничений. Вам не нужно находить минимальное решение, но количество совершённых перемещений не должно быть больше 200000 при условии, что количество дисков не превосходит 10.

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117672/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8